# Dangling Career with high quit frequency from PHP Developer Jobs - Need help

Tags: software-industry, new-job, quitting, relocation

I'm really worried about the way things went with my career. I've started computer science study by switching from a different field.

1. I was so much into programming that I got my first job after my first semester. I was offered 120$ per month only. The boss was a really hard person. The money was even hardly covering the fuel expenses to reach office. So, I quit after 1 month. Boss was angry.
2. Second job I got after some months, and I was offered about 250$ per month. I worked for 3 months and I was suddenly offered 900$/month from another company. The 250$ was covering only 10 days of month and remaining 20 days, I had to live on loan. The boss was good person but other job offer was only for immediate joining, I told boss and he said me that he can raise my salary to 400$/month. Other job salary was more than double and even the position was a lot better with a bit large team, so I quit, and the boss was angry as he had planned many other things for me to work on already.
3. I joined the third company. Things were good but the bosses on top were not even IT guys, so they kept saying to do more and I really worked to keep them happy. Still I was happy. There were a couple of complaints from this company. First, there was no arrangement of food. There was so dirty and even toxic street food available in day time (and we had to pay our self, I was cool with it but bad food and hard work really?). Company was in a really bad location that there was no Govt control over food quality. I still kept going with constant complaint about food. It was summer and temperature started to raise up-to 40-45 degree Celsius. My office was on top of building say hello to sun all the time. I kept working sweat in heat under only a fan. But it became too much with time as they kept promising that air-conditioner will be installed next Monday. So, 4 Mondays passed, and no Air Conditioner. Bosses stopped to attend office because of heat, we started to receive instructions in email from bosses, but me and few more guy (Those also quit before me) had to keep working because of deadlines. So, after 4 Mondays I quit. I was becoming so much physically sick, that I had to quit suddenly, even I didn't go to receive my last month salary as they had said to work for 1 week more before leaving and there was no way I was going to sit in that hell for a another single moment.
   One more thing, they had promised to pay double for extra hour/day. They never paid a single peny for extra hour, even though there were always extra days and hours.
4. Now I work as freelance developer for a nice small company in Canada. I make good money.

My aim was always to go to Europe/US/Canada to work as developer after finishing my study. Last month my degree completed and I got 2 Gold Medals in Computer Science and I already had won few small medals in past. The current company I work for as freelancer, is a small one and they can't offer me to join their office. Even though they like my work a lot. They even said me that they are looking into possibilities of taking me to their office but I don't they will be able to do so, as there are expenses and a lot of paperwork.

So, now I'm able to see a lot of vacancies in countries I want that match my skills and offer relocation.

But problem is experience. I worked:
1 month in first company, 
3 months in second,
4 months in third,
and for about 6 months I have been working as freelance.

One more strange thing, I was the best in all companies, they loved my work, and the way I quit, they just hate me now. So I can't expect any feedback from past companies.

How will I explain to new company recruiters the high quit frequency I had in past? I can't tell them stories like I did here, do I? 
Should I skip this in my experience section of CV/resume? 
Is it me who is bad? Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I know of no way to spin this into a positive, or even neutral, other than to either say "Yeah, I was an opinionated, impatient kid and something of a prima donna. I think I've learned better now" ... or to leave all those early/brief jobs off your resume entirely. I don't know if you _are_ bad, but it sounds like you were. (You could always have brought lunch, you know, if you didn't like what you were finding locally.)

Comment: What you hopefully learned from this is, is not to say 'yes' too quickly. You jumped into the first two jobs even though the wages were ridiculous. As for your CV just be honest about this, and say you have learned from it.

Comment: Don't worry too much about the early stuff. You will have a solid 6 months of experience at a good company that will provide good references. You took some bad jobs when you were a student, but you have learned.

Comment: where do you live?

Comment: @dynamic - good question. Your current location and visa status to the country you want to work in would be helpful to know. My answer made an assumption that you are living in Canada, but rereading this I may be mistaken?

Comment: "250$ per month" assuming you made more than 10 hours a week, Where in the world is this even allowed?

Comment: @RaoulMensink: $250/month is a really high salary in much of the world, even for working fulltime.

Comment: @Erik well if it cant pay for his fuel expenses it clearly aint a high salary.

Comment: Obviously it's not enough for him. But you asked "where in the world?" and the answer is "most of it, just not where he lives"

Comment: @Erik the kind of place that needs _developers_ isn't the type of place that should be paying $250/month.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Write "10 months PHP experience in different student jobs", if it wasn't fulltime calculate it down. Nobody really cares for the details and it's usual in that sector to have short term contracts.

If they really ask about it in an interview, tell them the companies made promises they didn't keep, working conditions were unhealthy, so you left as soon as it was clear it will not improve.

The one month gig i would forget about completely. And nothing wrong with working freelance for a while longer if you think lack of experience is a problem.

Comment: Freelance job experience has same value as office job?

Comment: @ArslanAfzal: Broadly, yes. In freelance computing sometimes more; it is easier to drop a freelancer than a member of staff, so if they kept you then you must have been good!

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked specifically about your resume, I assume you are worried both about the interview stage as well as trying to land an interview in the first place.

**Landing an interview:**

You will be looking to start as a junior developer somewhere, and will be competing against those with similar experience levels. **Demonstrate your skill through personal projects** if you are able. Don't skip past jobs on your resume, but highlight the best aspects of what you learned there, and what is relevant to the position you are applying to.

The market in Canada, at least where I am located is loaded with "Full Stack Developer" roles, which of course means something different for each company. You will want to investigate each role you apply for, **and invest the time to learn the basics of their technology stack.** I love when a developer takes the initiative to find out what technologies we use, and then **builds a sample project** demonstrating they can come up to speed very quickly.

**In the interview:**

The best advice I can give you is to **be honest and open about your experience and skill level**. There is no need to speak of negative experiences at prior jobs unless asked.

As someone who regularly interviews developers for junior positions in Canada, I can say at least personally that I'd be **more interested in learning your attitude** rather than knowing why these prior companies were hard to work for. I want to know that you will fit in with our team, and that you will contribute to a positive culture, making everyone around you enjoy having you on the team (both through your contributions and your attitude).

**A great attitude can get you a long way here.** Show true excitement in wanting to be part of a team.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly common for student workers to switch jobs frequently during studies, or have minimal work experience at all. List your education and medals first on your CV, and leave your work experience at the bottom, starting with the most recent. 6 months, 4 and 3 will not look so out of the ordinary. You can drop the 1 month employment, and possibly even the 4 and 3 months assignment. Don't list why you left or even bring it up in interviews or cover letters. If someone asks, just say "I received an opportunity that was more in line with my skill sets and interests" or "The assignment ended and I decided to focus on my studies." Lots of people leave jobs for poor working conditions and just gloss over it when applying for new jobs, so that they don't come off as a 'complainer'.

You may want to consider reaching out to your freelance client and ask them if they can refer more work or contacts to you. Let them know it's because you have more time on your hands now that you've completed your studies. They will either refer you to more clients that might be in position to help you with your long term goal, or they'll take the hint and connect you to someone who can offer you sponsorship.